# How to add projects into the solution that already in Source Control?

Tags: c#, tfs

I have two C# projects in TFS and I want to add them to another solution (that is in TFS as well), how to do this correct?

Tried to check out these projects and open the target solution > click "Add" > "existing project" but VS doesn't recognize this projects as they are under Source Control.

All I need now is:
1) Get copies of 2 projects that are already in Source control
2) Add them to my solution
3) Make changes in these projects
4) Check-in changes without affecting the original versions

Comment: Are they in two different TFS collections? Different servers? explain the TFS context.

Comment: @Askolein nope, they are all on the same server, I just need a copy that I can work with in my solution, make changes without affecting the original versions of these projects

Comment: Ok, do you want a copy. Very different question. You should edit your question about that. I'll write an answer about that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your two projects your `framework`. You should branch your framework and then link in your new solution to the appropriate branch.

1. Branch.

In Visual Studio, Team Explorer, browse your code collection

[image]

then right click on your framework source root folder and select "branch" . 
[image]

Then checkin your new branch.

2. Link
   In your new solution, click "Add Existing project..." and select the projects from the branch you just made.

The branched code basically is a full copy of your framework source code. But this copy is logically linked to the original one (for the TFS system). Nothing will be altered in the original one when you alter the branch, but you can merge selected changeset if you wish.

3. Folder structure

There are many possibilities about how to structure your TFS collection. My advice is to keep your main developping framework code in a `Trunk` folder and to have, at the same level, a `Branches` folder with all the versions in it. In the image above, there is only one branch made yet (named after a released version of my project to do hot fixes if needed, but this is just an example).

4. Merge

Then, you can merge changes if you want from the branch to the trunk (no obligation, just to avoid manual-error-prone code copy).

The [documentation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475908%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: While this solution works it gives you two potentially divergant code bases. This will increase your surface area for bugs. If merging changes happens infrequently and changes are made to both versions you will uncur a significant technical debt.

Comment: @mrk2 please note that @MrHirsh comment is important. He is pretty right when pointing out that having two separate code bases is hard to maintain. My answer deals correctly with your problem: how to handle a `fork` in TFS. But you need to think twice before taking the `fork` path.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing of code between different solutions is an ati-pattern that should be avoided.

If you have two projects that are required in more than one solution you should build and version them independently.

1) Split the two projects out to a new solution and folder structure.
2) Build and version your two shared assemblies
3) package both assemblies as Nuget packages and store on a network share or ProGet server
4) change the references for your two other solutions to use the new Nuget Package
5) create an automated build to refresh the Nuget package as you change the code.

You then have a shared component that you can make deliberate changes and deploy to your shared location. Each solution that takes a dependency will then notify you when the code is changed.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have two independent copies of you projects, then Askolein solution is your best bet.
However, if you want to reference the same projects from many different solutions then I think the following should work (some of it you listed already):

- in your workspace map and download directory that contains all projects and location of both solutions. So if you have $/tp1/solution1 for existing solution $/tp1/solution1/proj1 for project and $/tp1/solution2 for new solution then you map $/tp1 and best download all files under it
- now open solution2 (the one that you want to changes) and click Add->Existing project. You should be able to select projects as they exist on your local disk. You may need to "Add solution to source control" just to add your solution file. However projects are already in TFS and all your operations should not change their content (projects may be in many different solutions)

Good luck!

Comment: There is no circumstance when this is a good idea. The only result will be more bugs and due to an increase in complexity.

Comment: Could you please describe where the complexoty comes from? Solution is just a helper tool that allows you to open more than one project at once. I see  no problem having allprojects.sln, clientonly.sln and testprojects.sln

Comment: You have two solutions that have projects that are dependant on a single project. So if I change the code in one I may inadvertantly break the other. You also now make your build process more complicated as you have to map multiple folders in your build defenition. Again, this is never the solution to any problem.

Comment: I think you assume that you use solution to orchestrate your build which i explicitly said i dont do. I believe that using project references in msbuild is the right, clean solution and i saw it employed multiple times. I think that in every codebase bigger than 3 projects you will have common lib with utilities that other projects will be dependant on. If you change it you need to build other projects, using CI or some other way.

Comment: Triggering builds on projects independantly is not common practive nor is it encouraged by the product teams. Solutions provide features that Projects do not. See my answer below for a viable, supported, and scalable answer to the question.

Comment: I missed the comment describing that in fact mrk2 wants two independent copies. Your solution is perfect then. I'm still a little puzzled when it's actually encouraged vs sharing the code between different solutions/projects. I would love to hear what kind of features solution provide that projects do not. Working in TFS org, we used projects for everything. Now working for a company with ~1000 F# projects, we use project references exclusively (and complex msbuild customization). Solutions are just to load code into Visual Studio,